# How to set database jdbc url for Google Cloud SQL on quarkus?

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, jdbc, quarkus

I am trying to put my PostgreSQL DB onto Google Cloud SQL but encounter an error. To reproduce the error I do the following:

1. `mvn install`
2. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=yyy.json`
3. `java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

Which throws the following error:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "XXX" does not exist`

When looking at the official [documentation of quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud#using-cloud-sql-with-a-jdbc-driver) it mentions that I need to set the following properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other 
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql:///XXX 
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
quarkus.datasource.username=quarkus
quarkus.datasource.password=quarkus
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.cloudSqlInstance=project-id:gcp-region:instance 
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
```

I assume I did not enter the correct database name on the second line (`quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url`)
What url should be given as a property? The public IP address, the connection name, ...?

Comment: What's the XXX format?

Comment: Well, at the moment I entered the incoming ip address instead of 'xxx' , but that does not seem to work

Comment: ok replace XXX by your database name.

Comment: That is basically my question. What is the database name? I can see a connection name, a service account, but not a database name

Comment: XXX must be the database name. When you create your Cloud SQL instance, it's a database engine with default database and you can also create your own database. Use that database name instead of XXX: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere:

> XXX must be the database name. When you create your Cloud SQL instance, it's a database engine with a default database and you can also create your own database.

---

Reference:

- [Create and manage databases](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-databases)